# JQUERY TypeError: $ is undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

estoy trabajando en una aplicación PHP y en cierto punto necesito usar AJAX, tengo una página de búsqueda.php donde realizo una petición con ajax a un métodoX() y la petición se realiza correctamente. El problema es que al querer realizar otra petición ajax a otro métodoY() desde una página datos.php obtengo el error "TypeError: $ is undefined". Ambos métodos pertenecen a un mismo fichero js.

Esta es la forma que están importados los scripts tanto para búsqueda.php y datos.php:

```
<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


<script src="assets/js/lib/chart-js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/country/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/peticionesAJAX.js"></script>
```

Como se puede observar importo primero las librerías de JQUERY y la última línea es mi fichero con métodoX() y métodoY()

Estos son los métodos:

```
function metodoX(idUsuario){
datos = {"tipoPag":"eliminar", "ip":idUsuario}
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/pagPHP/controlador/cDatos_Persona.php",
    data: datos,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(info){
        if(info == "1"){ //si el usuario se eliminó correctamente
            swal("Completado!", "Usuario eliminado", "success");
        }else{
            swal("Error!", "No se pudo eliminar el usuario", "error");
        }
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        console.log("AJAX ENVIADOSE");
    }
});}

function metodoY(){
var datos = getDatos("nuevo");
console.log(datos);
if(validarDatos(datos)){
    console.log($);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/pagPHP/controlador/cDatos_Persona.php",
        data: datos,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(info){
            if(info == "1"){ //si el usuario se ingresó correctamente
                swal("Completado!", "Usuario ingresado", "success");
            }else{
                swal("Error!", "No se pudo ingresar el usuario", "error");
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log("AJAX ENVIADOSE");
        }
    });
}}
```

El metodoX() no me da ningún problema, pero al querer ejecutar AJAX en métodoY() tengo el error "TypeError: $ is undefined" y como ya mencioné los scripts se importan de igual manera en ambos archivos php. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hola en la función "metodoY()" Tienes esto "console.log($);" lo cual se interpreta como que estas mandando a la consola la variable "$" por ende te suelta dicho error borra o comenta esta linea.

Comment: esa línea era solo para ver que porqué me daba el error! quitando la línea pasa lo mismo

Comment: entonces deberías revisar las funciones (getDatos y validarDatos ) que son invocadas desde "metodoY()" o si cDatos_Persona.php tiene un error en la sección de ingresar.